# Dynamic python variable creation

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I have a variable like YEAR = 2022
Now I want to make a automate variable like Sales_Report_'YEAR's value(2022).
How can I create this type of dynamic variable name in python ?

Comment: Please look up "dynamic programming". This is not it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vars() or globals() if you want to add a new variable to the module's namespace

```
vars()['Sales_Report_YEAR'] = 2022
globals()['Sales_Report_MONTH'] = 11
```

If you want to add a new variable to an instance of a class, you can use setattr()

```
class MyClass:
    pass
instance = MyClass()
setattr(instance, 'Sales_Report_YEAR', 2022)
```

And you also can use setattr() for add a variable to the module

```
import sys
thismodule = sys.modules[__name__]
setattr(thismodule, 'Sales_Report_YEAR', 2022)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that.  Create a dictionary with years for keys:

```
YEAR = 2022
SALES_REPORTS = {}
SALES_REPORTS[YEAR] = "Whatever you want here as a report"
```

You could create a container class and do some magic with it, but for most cases dictionary would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to create dynamically key names and associate the value you need.

```py
sales_reports = {}

x = 0

while x < 10:
    # Calculating the year
    year = (current year)

    # Creating the key name
    key_name = 'Sales_Report_' + str(year)

    # Calculating data_report
    data_report = (calculating report data)

    # Appending the value  and the key name into the dictionary and assigning the appropriate data report to it
    sales_reports[key_name] = data_report
    
    # Increasing the value of x to keep iterating until the value is equal with 10
    x = x + 1
```

You can try and use other data structures like python [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html).